# How to download a file in C++\wxWidgets

Tags: c++, download, wxwidgets

How may I download a file in C++ with wxWidgets?

Been googling and everything and nothing shows up! Help appreciated!

Comment: Download from which location? FTP/HTTP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [wxHTTP](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxHTTP) class for that.

**wxHTTP Example Code:**

```
#include <wx/sstream.h>
#include <wx/protocol/http.h>

wxHTTP get;
get.SetHeader(_T("Content-type"), _T("text/html; charset=utf-8"));
get.SetTimeout(10); // 10 seconds of timeout instead of 10 minutes ...

while (!get.Connect(_T("www.google.com")))
    wxSleep(5);

wxApp::IsMainLoopRunning();

wxInputStream *httpStream = get.GetInputStream(_T("/intl/en/about.html"));

if (get.GetError() == wxPROTO_NOERR)
{
    wxString res;
    wxStringOutputStream out_stream(&res);
    httpStream->Read(out_stream);

    wxMessageBox(res);
}
else
{
    wxMessageBox(_T("Unable to connect!"));
}

wxDELETE(httpStream);
get.Close();
```

If you want more flexible solution consider using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where you want to 'download' it from, and how the file server allows files to be downloaded.  The server might use FTP, or HTTP, or something more obscure.  There is no way to tell from your question which has no useful information in it.

In general, I would not use wxWidgets for this task.  wxWidgets is a GUI frmaework, with some extras for various things that may or may not be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

From `HTTP` as **Andrejs** suggest, from `FTP` using `wxFTP`

```
wxFTP ftp;

// if you don't use these lines anonymous login will be used
ftp.SetUser("user");
ftp.SetPassword("password");

if ( !ftp.Connect("ftp.wxwindows.org") )
{
    wxLogError("Couldn't connect");
    return;
}

ftp.ChDir("/pub");
wxInputStream *in = ftp.GetInputStream("wxWidgets-4.2.0.tar.gz");
if ( !in )
{
    wxLogError("Coudln't get file");
}
else
{
    size_t size = in->GetSize();
    char *data = new char[size];
    if ( !in->Read(data, size) )
    {
        wxLogError("Read error");
    }
    else
    {
        // file data is in the buffer
        ...
    }

    delete [] data;
    delete in;
}
```

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxftp.html#wxftp

Answer (score 0):

You did not define what "downloading a file" means to you.

If you want to use HTTP to retrieve some content, you should use an [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) client library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) and issue the appropriate HTTP `GET` request.